# complex if( ) or enum?

Tags: java, enums

In my app, I need to branch out if the input matches some specific 20 entries.

I thought of using an enum

```
public enum dateRule { is_on, is_not_on, is_before,...}
```

and a switch on the enum constant to do a function

```
switch(dateRule.valueOf(input))
{
  case is_on : 
  case is_not_on :
  case is_before :
  .
  .
  .
  // function()
  break;
}
```

But the input strings will be like 'is on', 'is not on', 'is before' etc without _ between words. 
I learnt that an enum cannot have constants containing space.

Possible ways I could make out:

1, Using if statement to compare 20 possible inputs that giving a long if statement like

```
if(input.equals("is on") ||
   input.equals("is not on") || 
   input.equals("is before") ...)   { // function() }
```

2, Work on the input to insert _ between words but even other input strings that don't come under this 20 can have multiple words.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: In Java 7 you can switch on a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. They guided me here.

This is almost same as other answers, just a bit simplified.

To summarize, I need to compare the input string with a set of 20 strings and

if they match, do something. Else, do something else.

Static set of strings to which input needs to be compared : 
is on,is not on,is before,is after, etc 20 entries

I created an enum

```
public enum dateRules
{
   is_on
   ,is_not_on
   ,is_before
   ,is_after
   .
   .
   .
}
```

and switching on formatted value of input

```
if(isARule(in = input.replace(" ","_"))
{
   switch(dateRule.valueOf(in))
   {
      case is_on,
      case is_not_on,
      case is_before, ...
   }
}
```

I copied the formatted value of 'input' to 'in' so that I can reuse input without another replace of '_' with ' '.

```
private static boolean isARule(String value)
  {
    for(dateRule rule : dateRule.values())
    {
      if(rule.toString().equals(value))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Problem solved.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936895/1297564

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to seperate the enum identifier from the value. Something like this:

```
public enum MyEnumType
{
    IS_BEFORE("is before"),
    IS_ON("is on"),
    IS_NOT_ON("is not on")

    public final String value;

    MyEnumType(final String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You can also add methods to the enum-type (the method can have arguments as well), something like this:

```
public boolean isOnOrNotOn()
{
    return (this.value.contentEquals(IS_ON) || this.value.contentEquals(IS_NOT_ON));
}
```

Use in switch:

```
switch(dateRule.valueOf(input))
{
    case IS_ON: ...
    case IS_NOT_ON: ...
    case IS_BEFORE: ...
}
```

And when you get the value of IS_ON like for example `System.out.println(IS_ON)` it will show `is on`.

Comment: I get the error `dateRule() in dateRule cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)`. The IDE suggestion is to define a constructor.

Comment: @Student Then that is my suggestion too :) Sorry about that, I only posted a partial code. I have added some more now.

Comment: Thanks! No more error now. :) But I get is_on on `System.out.println(is_on);`

Comment: @Student You might need to use `MyEnumType.IS_ON` for that.

Comment: Yes, I did that only. dateRule.is_on has value is_on.

Comment: @Student Are you sure you have written this part correctly? `    IS_BEFORE("is before"), 
    IS_ON("is on"), 
    IS_NOT_ON("is not on")`. The value within the parentesis should be the value that the enums have.

Comment: Does case matter? If not, then yes I have is_on("is on"), is_not_on("is not on"), is_before("is before") etc in the enum.

Comment: @Student when you print out the value print out `MyEnumType.is_on.value` also, don't forget that when you specify the enums use `is_on("is on")` and so on to specify them.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own version of `valueOf` method inside the enum (just don't call it `valueOf`).

```
public enum State {
    IS_ON,
    IS_OFF;

    public static State translate(String value) {
        return valueOf(value.toUpperCase().replace(' ', '_'));
    }
}
```

Simply use it like before.

```
State state = State.translate("is on");
```

The earlier switch statement would still work.

Comment: Started from here and on further simplifying the control flow ended up in the solution I posted. Learnt a lot. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 7, you can also choose the middle road here, and do a `switch` statement with Strings:

```
switch (input) {
    case "is on":
        // do stuff
        break;
    case "is not on":
        // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will help me sometime in future for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not really breaking the concept up enough, both solutions are brittle...

Look at your syntax

"is", can remove, seems to be ubiquitous

"not", optional, apply a ! to the output comparison

on, before, after, apply comparisons.

So do a split between spaces. Parse the split words to ensure they exist in the syntax definition and then do a step-by-step evaluation of the expression passed in. This will allow you to easily extend the syntax (without having to add an "is" and "is not" for each combination and keep your code easy to read.

Having multiple conditions munged into one for the purposes of switch statements leads to huge bloat over time.