# What is the difference between `Enum.name()` and `Enum.toString()`?

Tags: java, enums

After reading the documentation of `String java.lang.Enum.name()` I am not sure I understand when to use [name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7//docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) and when to use [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7//docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration. Most programmers should use the toString method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name. This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release.

In particular, even though the documentation says to prefer `toString()`, Java's own [StandardLocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html) enumeration uses `name` when I would have thought the documentation suggested otherwise.

```
public String getName() { return name(); }
```

Furthermore `Enum` implements `toString()` as,

```
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

and I cannot think of a situation where a user defined enumeration would overwrite `toString()` so `name()` and `toString()` are almost always exactly the same.

1. Can you please explain why ignoring the documentation and always using `name()` is a bad idea?
2. What about the phrase "will not vary from release to release". If name will not vary, does it imply that `java.lang.Enum.toString()` would?

Comment: By default, an enum's `.toString()` is its `.name()`. However, you can override `.toString()`, not `.name()`.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

The main difference between `name()` and `toString()` is that `name()` is a `final` method, so it cannot be overridden. The `toString()` method returns the same value that `name()` does by default, but `toString()` can be overridden by subclasses of Enum.

Therefore, if you need the *name of the field itself*, use `name()`. If you need a *string representation of the value of the field*, use `toString()`.

For instance:

```
public enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY;

    public String toString() {
        return name().charAt(0) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

In this example, 
`WeekDay.MONDAY.name()` returns "MONDAY", and
`WeekDay.MONDAY.toString()` returns "Monday".

`WeekDay.valueOf(WeekDay.MONDAY.name())` returns `WeekDay.MONDAY`, but `WeekDay.valueOf(WeekDay.MONDAY.toString())` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 37):

Use **toString()** when you want to present information to a user (including a developer looking at a log). Never rely in your code on `toString()` giving a specific value. Never test it against a specific string. If your code breaks when someone correctly changes the `toString()` return, then it was already broken.

If you need to get the exact name used to declare the enum constant, you should use **name()** as `toString` may have been overridden.

Answer (score 25):

Use `toString` when you need to display the name to the user.

Use `name` when you need the name for *your program* itself, e.g. to identify and differentiate between different enum values.